# Why am I getting this error: Variable does not exist: targetObjectIds

Tags: apex, approval-process, custom-controller, processinstancenode

Good day, 
Still new to SF. I'm trying to put extra columns on the Items To Approve table in SF Classic. But I'm getting variable doesn't exist error. this is my controller. Please assist:

```
public class approval_controller {

    public class item_wrapper {
        public id id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string objtype { get; set; }
        public string mostrecent { get; set; }
        public string DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public id approvalid { get; set; }
        public string hierarchy { get; set; }
    } 
    public List <Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c> insRenewals {get;set;}
    public list<item_wrapper> items_to_approve { get; set; }

    public approval_controller() {
    items_to_approve = new list<item_wrapper>();
    for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem item:[select processinstance.targetobjectid, processinstance.targetobject.name
                                      from processinstanceworkitem where actorid = :userinfo.getuserid()]) 
                {
                                        item_wrapper itemWrapper = new item_wrapper();
                                        itemWrapper.Id = item.processinstance.targetobjectid;
                                        itemWrapper.Name = item.processinstance.targetobject.name;
                                        items_to_approve.add(itemWrapper);
                }

        List<Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c> insRenewals =  [SELECT Hierarchy__c
                                                          FROM Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c
                                                          WHERE Id IN: targetObjectIds];

    }
    public String REASSIGNnavigation() {
        String url='';
        string myParam = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('myParam');
        url='https://'+ System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()+'/'+ myParam +'/e?et=REASSIGN';    
        return url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never defined such a variable. Here's a modification:

```
// Place to store the target Ids for the second query
Set<Id> targetObjectIds = new Set<Id>();
for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem item:[select processinstance.targetobjectid, processinstance.targetobject.name
                                  from processinstanceworkitem where actorid = :userinfo.getuserid()]) 
            {
                                    item_wrapper itemWrapper = new item_wrapper();
                                    itemWrapper.Id = item.processinstance.targetobjectid;
                                    itemWrapper.Name = item.processinstance.targetobject.name;
                                    items_to_approve.add(itemWrapper);
                                    // Store object Ids for next query
                                    targetObjectIds.add(item.processinstance.targetobjectid);
            }
```

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox I'm gonna try it and see if it works

Comment: the above code worked. However, it seems I'm still missing something. How do I set the hierarchy value on the items_to_approve item to the value of that insRenewal item's hierarchy name? @sfdcfox

Comment: @ApexNewBie12 You'd probably want to put the query results in to a map, then you could pull out the appropriate value per target per record when creating the wrapper items. Starting from where you are now, change the last query to: `Map<id, Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c> managers = new Map<Id, Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c>(
    [SELECT Hierarchy__c FROM Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c WHERE Id IN: targetObjectIds]
);` and then `for(item_wrapper wrapper: items_to_approve) {
    wrapper.hierarchy = managers.get(wrapper.id);
}`.

Comment: I ended up with this:

 `Map<Id, Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c> insRenewals = new Map<Id, Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c>                               
      ([SELECT Hierarchy__c FROM Hierarchy_Renewal_Manager__c WHERE Id IN: targetObjectIds]);
        for (item_wrapper wrapper: items_to_approve){
        wrapper.hierarchy = insRenewals.get(wrapper.id).Hierarchy__c;
        }`

Will this work? If so, any idea on a test class? @sfdcfox

Comment: @ApexNewBie12 It looks like it should. For a test class, you'll insert some test data, set the page (Test.setCurrentPage), set any parameters,  construct the controller, examine the state of the controller (assertions), then call the REASSIGNnavigation method, and assert its output. We've got lots of examples on how to use test classes here on SFSE, feel free to browse [tag:unit-test].